# Is it possible to make cache session expiry time based on put instead of get

Tags: apex, platform-cache

In Apex, when we put information into cache.session, there is a method to set the expiry time based on seconds.

However, that expiry time seems to be re-calculated every time we put or get into/from the cache session. Is it possible to re-calculate that time only based on get, instead of both get and put?

Comment: As you talking about the Platform Cache? Please clarify in the question and perhaps add more tags?

Comment: @PhilW Sure, added.

Comment: Interested to know why?

Comment: @KeithC Because our other side of the api expires token every several minutes after retrieval.